# sharing site running on IIS with another member on the network

Tags: wcf, iis, networking, iis-7.5

I have a set of wcf services, running locally on my desktop machine, at the url - http://localhost.mysite.com with an example of an endpoint being http://localhost.mysite.com/myservice.svc

My PC is on a network with other PC's.

I know its possible, but I cant work away how, that a user of another PC on the network can navigate to above end point. They can see my PC on the network by going to My Network Places but dont know what url to call to access the endpoint? And do I need to configure anything at my end? I expected maybe my colleague may need to insert my pc name or ip address in the url. I also have other sites running in my IIS.

Comment: You'll need to use either the IP address or machine name of your PC.  localhost is just that - local to the machine.  It's not visible to other machines on the network.

Comment: So the url should be http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/myservice.svc ? How does it know which site in IIS?

Comment: The same way it knows which site when your running on localhost.  The address can be the same, the only thing you need to change is from localhost to an IP address or machine name/DNS name.